# Dealing with time bound instances in Weka

Tags: machine-learning, weka

I'm new to Weka. I'm running some algorithms against a dataset that has vector input for each instance. For example:

```
Instance ID, Timestamp, Sensor 1, Sensor 2, ...
1, 1, <some data>, <some data>, ..
1, 2, <some data>, <some data>, ..
1, 3, <some data>, <some data>, ..
2, 1, <some data>, <some data>, ..
2, 2, <some data>, <some data>, ..
...
```

Are there some settings in Weka I can change to allow the program to classify based on a vector of tuples for each instance, rather than each row?